# Training a Model with 2D Input Array and 3D Output Array

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, image-processing

I have a feature array 'a' in size (422, 750) and I have a colored image 'img' in size (422, 750, 3). I want to create a machine learning model where my input X is a and output y is img. I tried Decision three regression but it kept giving me errors since these two arrays are not the same size. Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: You would better use Neural Networks.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but I should be using only machine learning teachniques @ghchoi